# local_planner seeing invisible wall

Tags: ros, rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[image: image description]

As seen in the image, the robot is detecting a curved wall in front of it and is stopping the route. However there isn't any wall in that position, just the ones on the sides, as seen on the map. What could it be?

[image: image description]

Again, there is nothing in front of the robot, but it is seeing a wall

I'm also receiving these warnings:

```
[WARN] [1683209662.283217847]: Map update loop missed its desired rat e of 5.0000Hz... the loop actually took 0.2276 seconds.     
[WARN] [1683209662.457042787]: Control loop missed its desired rate o f 5.0000Hz... the loop actually took 0.2017 seconds.
```

I don't know if it has something to do with it, as I have been receiving this warnings way before this problem.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/415008/local_planner-seeing-invisible-wall/) by [Grunthorin](https://answers.ros.org/users/146828/grunthorin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2023-05-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2023-05-04**:
Please do not post screenshots of text. Instead, copy/paste the text into the description and format it with the 101010 button.

**Comment by [Grunthorin](https://answers.ros.org/users/146828/grunthorin/) on 2023-05-04**:
Thanks for the headsup! It's fixed now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We found out that the prohibition areas plugin were consuming too much of our robot, removing them stopped that problem. (Prohibition areas made our Raspberry CPU go to 100%, while without it it wont go past 25%..).
Probably sometimes it would freeze and not compute its odometry correctly, therefore thinking that it was seeing a wall when it wasn't.

---

Originally posted by [Grunthorin](https://answers.ros.org/users/146828/grunthorin/) with karma: 26 on 2023-05-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This symptom can happen when the robot's current pose is inaccurate (it's usually the odometry.) If the current `map->sensor` pose is inaccurate, then any transformation of the sensor data into the map frame is also inaccurate.

---

Originally posted by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) with karma: 4903 on 2023-05-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Grunthorin](https://answers.ros.org/users/146828/grunthorin/) on 2023-05-04**:
But it happen out of nowhere, it is working normally and all of sudden it just puts the wall there. Is it still an odometry problem?